# SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender in custom code

Tags: 2010, people-search

OOB People search result web part uses control SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender for displaying recent content created by the user. How can I use that control in custom code? If I add the control in custom code, I get error

> Unknown server tag 'SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender'.

What reference should I have in my .master page to get this working? Thanks!

Also SEARCHWC:PeopleCoreResultPopupControl seems to be used on the OOB Web Part.

**UPDATE:** 
According to reflector PopupControlExtender is found from Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls, still this doesn't do any good

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the tag declaration on your page

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="tagPrefixName" Namespace="namespace" Assembly="fullAssemblyName" %>
```

of

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="tagPrefixName" TagName="tagName" src="pathToTheControl" %>
```

Could you look at the working page that contains SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender and copy past the registration which contains TagPrefix="SEARCHWC" ?

Comment: If I add OOB People Search Results Web Part on my page, it contains SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender, yet I cannot find any reference to it anywhere. That OOB web part on the same page with my custom web part, will work just fine with that SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender control.

Comment: try to use `<%@ Register TagPrefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>`, but I'm not sure that it is a control that you use :)

Comment: Thanks, just looked that up using reflector and tried, but it doesn't help. Strange.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/872dbbf4-c64c-46ef-aa59-3d0d9a3ff5f1)... may be it will be helpfull.

Comment: Unfortunately that post doesn't discuss my issue, although on the post there you can see the SEARCHWC control just like it is on OOB search results web part.

Comment: What exception have you got when you add registration above?

Comment: Same "Unknown server tag 'SEARCHWC:PopupControlExtender'". I have verified that I'm modifying the correct .master page :)

Comment: Sorry, but I does not have any idea ((